# Only one google play dependency, but all the google play libraries are on the app external libraries

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, android-multidex

I have the 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0' on my android app gradle. first i had the 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0', but I changed it to 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0' because of the 65 limit problem.

The 65 limit problem hasn't gone, I am using the multidex enable, to run my app and i don't think I should have this problem. here are all my app's dependecies. i haven't count the methods of each dependecy( I don't know how), but i have worked with this ones in other projects and i haven't had this problem.

```
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12' 
compile    'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0' 
compile    'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0' 
compile    'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0' 
compile    'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0' 
compile    'com.android.support:design:23.3.0' 
compile    'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+' 
compile    'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.0' 
compile    'com.bit6.sdk:bit6-sdk:0.9.6' 
compile    'com.bit6.ui:bit6-ui:0.9.6'    
compile    'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0' 
compile    'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)' 
compile    'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
```

I find really suspicious that on "External Libraries" all the google play services still appear.

[External libraries capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyDf4.png)

Do I have to use the multidex library to work? is this libraries in the picture, which i don't use, causing my method count to increase?

The build and run of my app is taking way to long, 20mins. My project has 16 classes with more or less 5 methods each one.

Comment: did you follow all these instructions? http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Comment: here is the bash script you can count the methods with https://github.com/mihaip/dex-method-counts

Comment: What is the output of `./gradlew androidDependencies`? That'll tell you if one of your dependency is bringing in the entirety of Google Play services.

Comment: actually other dependencies(bit6) where the ones causing the 65k limit problem. thanx for the help